# Avoiding recursive imports in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I use models very frequently in `forms.py` (obviously), and I now want to be able to get a form in `models.py`. I can think of a convoluted way around this, but it seems like there should be a way to do this without recursive importing, but still relatively simply. Is there any way to access a form I define in `forms.py` without importing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely import `forms.py` inside the function/method:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def my_method(self):
        from my_app.forms import MyForm
        ...
```